# Conditional distribution in a Bayes net

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I have this Bayesian network where variable C is dependent on variables A and B. I want to know how come

$
P(B|C) = \frac{P(B)}{P(B)+(1-P(B))P(A)}
$

Comment: Where have you obtained the expression? There is no $C$ on the right-hand-side, so for sure this cannot be in general true. In other words: more context required.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala. http://astro.temple.edu/~tuc17157/pdfs/coric2014sdm.pdf page 6

Comment: Could you add the information about the context (the DAG and what the variables represent) into the question.